# Single Sign On Chrome extension and website ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-chrome-extension, single-sign-on

I've a website ASP.NET Web API which have scaffolded auth code (I used built-in google auth), it's has both api và mvc view. Then I'm building a Google Chrome Extension which to be a client of the website.
I'm looking for solution / best practice to have single-sign-on among this system. Should my website have to auth first and store token in cookies. And chrome extension will send request with token queried in the specific website cookies. If no token has been found, the chrome extension will open website auth form (google login form) to the user and continue website auth flow. the flow end will trigger chrome extension's callback to repeat the request. My design is very manual handle and I hope there's a better practice I can learn.

Comment: Did you ever discover the answer to this? I would greatly love to hear how you may have solved this. Thanks